# Google Map Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete. How do I control the width of the input text box? And how do I control the width of the drop down menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input has the `searchTextField` id, so this simple css rule would do the trick:

```
#searchTextField {
    width: 500px;
}
```

The drop down menu will scale accordingly, but if you want to change it you should add:

```
.pac-container {
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

The `!important` is needed because the width is applied inline to the dropdown using the `style` attribute, and this can't be overriden.